# Getting the last value of an Array and showing it under X axis

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, flotr

```
var NewdateData[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,1,23,45,56]
```

This `NewdateData` is dynamically filled from database depending upon the selection made from the user interface.

I am using this `NewdateData` for displaying under the X axis Charts.

The issue I am facing is that, the values are not taken till the end , I want to have the last value to have under the X axis Labels.

```
xaxis: {tickFormatter: function(n)
{
    var k = Math.round(n);
    return NewdateData[k]; 
}
```

I am using [flotr](http://code.google.com/p/flotr/).

Comment: what i want is , i want to have the provious values and if its the last value i want that also  so basically i assume if and else withinn return NewdateData[k];

Answer (score 16):

You can get the last value of an array with:

```
NewdateData[NewdateData.length-1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much , is it possible to use both return NewdateData[k]; and NewdateData[NewdateData.length-1]; to return ??

Comment: @user663724, use json or array if u want to return multiple values

Comment: Is there a better solution with ES7?

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party, but for posterity: in ES2015/ES6 you can use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Doesn't mutate the array and a negative number gives you elements from the end of the array as a new array.

So to get the last element:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let last = arr.slice(-1); // last = 5
```

Comment: When you're already slicing the end of array, you don't need to pass '0' index.

Comment: `.slice` returns an array

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have enough points to comment on Radman’s post., but his solution is wrong.

> let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; let last = arr.slice(-1); // last = 5

Returns [5], not 5.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into **a new array** object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

The correct answer:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let last = arr.slice(-1)[0];
```

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with the map function.

this is the array what I want to pick the last item from it:-

```
const animals = ['Dodo', 'Tiger', 'Penguin', 'Dodo'];
```

loop over the array using map function to use the index parameter and compare it with animals array length:-

```
animals.map((animal, index) => animals.length -1 === index ? console.log("last item selected :)" + animal) : console.log("i'm not the last item"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now we are living with ES6 features

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

const [a, ...b] = arr.reverse();

console.log(a)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and convenient way is to use **Array.prototype.at()**

```
function returnLast(arr) {
  return arr.at(-1);
}

const cart = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];
const lastItem = returnLast(cart);

console.log(lastItem)  //pear
```

or just

```
const lastItem = cart.at(-1)
```